# Binding with parent proprety WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

here is my code: (explanation of my problem after)

```
<TreeView x:Name="playlist" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Playlist}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding file}">

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Names" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                    <Button Content="add" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.Add_file, ElementName=playlist}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Names, Path=Text}">
                    </Button>

</StackPanel>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="File_name" Text="{Binding}">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.Current_playlist, ElementName=playlist}"
                                                           CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Name,Path=Text}">

                                    </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.Lecture, ElementName=playlist}"
                                                           CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=File_name,Path=Text}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Ok, so my first eventtrigger does not work. I'm trying to send the value of my textblock named "Name"(just above). But he doesn't find this name. So he send me a null value.

I know that the problem is comming from the lign
`<TextBlock x:Name="File_name" Text="{Binding}">`
I'm changing my datacontext so i'd like to be in the parent datacontext to get property "Text" of the texblock named "Name".

Comment: If the ElementName binding doesn't work, it might mean that it is not in the visual tree.  In that case, you would have to use a "data context proxy" or a similar technique to access that parent data context.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `ElementName` in your binding, why not use `ReleativeSource`?  Use `FindAncestor` to get the `TreeView` and bind to the value on it's `DataContext`.

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.Current_playlist, ElementName=playlist}"
```

becomes

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.Current_playlist, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TreeView}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the Command is working fine, it's the CommandParameter who doesn't work. I tried what you give, but still doesn't work.